# Text and button on top of background image

Tags: html, css, button, text, background-image

I am trying to add text and a button on top of a background image I cannot figure out the CSS for the margins and positions on liquid page.If you can steer me in the right direction or help. Thank you!

```css
.feature_home{
    margin:?
    position:?
  }
.feature_image{
    margin:?
    position:?
  }
.feature_text{
    margin:?
    position:?
  }
.feature_button{
    margin:?
    position:?
  }
```

```html
<div class="feature_home">
<img class="feature_image" alt="Thanks For your guys help" src="images/xyz.com">
<p class="feature_text">I really appreciate your guys help!</p>
<a class="feature_button" href="/xyz-101/">Thank You</a>
</div>
</div>
```

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x background Image               x                
x                   Text Here:   X
x                   Text Here:   x                             
x                                x
x                   Button Here: x  
x                                x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

It wont let me ad an image until I get 10 reputations to post image.

Comment: Could you make a demo, perhaps in a fiddle or jsbin?

Comment: @GiacomoPaita he's already got a code snippet, why are you asking for a fiddle too?

Comment: Giacomo Paita thanks for comment! I am not really familiar with js. Is this still possible to create with html or css?

Comment: Thanks dave7 for looking @ this!

Comment: Thanks dave for looking @ this!

Comment: Consider using CSS [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
.feature_home{
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: right;
    width: 350px; /* image width */
    height: 150px; /* image height */
}

.feature_image{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="feature_home">
    <img class="feature_image" alt="Thanks For your guys help" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    <p class="feature_text">I really appreciate your guys help!</p>
    <a class="feature_button" href="/xyz-101/">Thank You</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7zvL5zto/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can just get rid of `<img>` and use `background-image` style on `.feature_home` and give it a `position:relative;` so you can position `feature_home` and `feature_button` like you want it.

Here you have HTML code:

```
<div class="feature_home" style="background-image:url(image);">
   <p class="feature_text">I really appreciate your guys help!</p>
   <a class="feature_button" href="/xyz-101/">Thank You</a>
</div>
```

And here is CSS:

```
.feature_home{
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    background-position:center center;
    background-size:100%;
}
.feature_text{
    position:absolute;
    right:2px;
    bottom:15px;
}
.feature_button{
    right:2px;
    bottom:2px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

All the values are for example :)

http://jsfiddle.net/cjtdhcLr/

Comment: Why are you mixing CSS with inline style..?

Comment: Because it's easier to manipulate when you want few boxes like this, you just changing background-image of each box and rest stays the same

Comment: In that case, it is very easy to give the element an id and add it from CSS file... mixing CSS and inline styles is a very bad practice...

Comment: Ok, but what if you have for example a PHP while and you want to display different images from DB in different boxes? I'm not saying that is the only way, but it's pretty easier to do like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that will work, and instead of the red background choose your image

```css
.feature_home {
  width:400px;
  background:red;
  float:left;
  padding:15px
}
        
p {
  text-align:right;
}
        
a {     
  float:left; 
  text-align:right;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="feature_home">
  <p class="feature_text">I really appreciate your guys help!</p>
  <a class="feature_button" href="/xyz-101/">Thank You</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks hbogs,Piotrek Ryszka,Marian and all who took a look @ this! You guys rock! I hope you guys have a great day! Thanks Again!

Comment: Moderater you can mark this as closed! What a great coding community! And thanks Stackoverflow!

Comment: @x09 if this answer helped you best, then it is up to you to mark it as the accepted answer. Click the checkmark at the upper-left of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.feature_home{
background-image:url("http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-biBlhcDYdZI/ULjLQeeCwzI/AAAAAAAAAmo/T9M9YTcMeWY/s400/BackgroundPanel.pngg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-left:25px;
padding-right:25px;
height:200px;
width:321px;
position:absolute;
  }
.feature_button{
color:white;
position:absolute;
right:30px;
  }
</style>

<div class="feature_home">
<p class="feature_text">I really appreciate your guys help!</p>
<a class="feature_button" href="/xyz-101/">Thank You</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Use position:absolute; http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Absolute Positioning
An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static. If no such element is found, the containing block is :

This should be enough to get you started. I would not use an actual img. You would be better assigning the image as the background of your feature_home div. See the css background-image.

if you have to use the img then you will need to use z-index to position the elements in layers with the image set below all of the other items.